# Using variables as selectors with Selenium 2 Webdriver by.cssselector

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to write Selenium 2 Webdriver automated tests in C#.
I have searched high and low for examples of using variables as selectors and have found nothing that seems to work. The one example I have found of a variable used as a selector had the variable with $ prefix and enclosed in {}.
An example of what I am trying to do is below:

```
string surveyName = "Selenium test survey";
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr[svd='${surveyName}']"))
```

I get the error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Unexpected error. Unable to find element using     css: tr[svd='${surveyName}']
```

If I 'hard code' the selector like this:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr[svd='Selenium test survey']"))
```

it finds the element.

svd is an attribute of the tr element. I am trying to select a row within a table by the value of this attribute. The text will be different for each test and so must be a variable.

I have tried expressing the variable a number of different ways but had no luck making this  work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string surveyName = "Selenium test survey";
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(String.Format("tr[svd='{0}']", surveyName))
```

will do what you want. This is c# so when it takes a string you can do all kinds of things to get that string

Comment: Great question...i was having the same issues and your answer helped me out a lot, @Caspar.  I have one question though.  If i want to select an ID of and input element and the ID is `Mileage_departmentForm_16` i know i can just use `(By.CssSelector("input[id-'Mileage_departmentForm_16']"))` but is there a way i could do something like select an id that _starts with_ "Mileage"? Thanks!

Comment: Oh wow, i feel dumb...just figured it out.  You have to use `(By.CssSelector("input[id^='Mileage_departmentForm_16']"))`.  I imagine all of the other types of selecting works as well (starts with, ends with, has, etc).